# How can i find the trigger of an acpi event?

Tags: windows-event-log, acpi

My Server shutsdown . Evertime at midnight.

The acpi Event power_button is triggered. at /etc/acpi/events/power_button
power_button:

```
# care about the power button
event=button/power.*
action=/usr/lib/acpid/power_button
```

How can i find out the "Caller" or the Trigger of this event ?

Answer (score 1):

`power_button` is a script, so all you need is to save executing backtrace from that script. The idea is to write a script that analyzes processes tree from launched `power_button` upwards and the caller process should be somewhere within.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685435/bash-stacktrace/1438241#1438241). Put the script into `/usr/lib/acpid/power_button` and save its output to a file: that should identify the offender unless the reason is not a data-center's cleaner guy :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends exactly on your flavour of linux, but I've found this helpful in the past:

```
/var/log/acpi.log
```

Also using "lastcomm" to find the preceding processes.